# How does the conditional operator change the value of the variable b in the program below?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;
    *((a+1 == 1) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is 0, 2, 2. How does the conditional statement change the value of variable b in C?

Comment: The first conditional expression returns a pointer, which you dereference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at this row:

```
*((a+1 == 1) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;
```

`(a+1 == 1)` is `1` so this becomes

```
*(1 ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;
```

Which is

```
*(&b) = a ? b : c;
```

Since `a` is still `0`, that is

```
*(&b) = c;
```

This means that the address of `b` is taken, and the value that it points to (`b`) is set to `c`, which is `2`. So in the end, what it does is changing `b` to `2`.

If the ternary operator (`?`) confuses you, you can read up on it [here](https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html).

Comment: That's a great explanation @Blaze, thank you so much!